# Android 4.x on HTC One - USB debugging mode automatically turns itself off

Tags: android, usb-debugging, htc-android

I just got an HTC One (T-Mobile) for testing an application we're developing.  Currently the app requires USB Debugging to be switched on.  With the HTC One, running Android 4.1.1, I can switch USB Debugging on, but after a period of time (hours sometimes) it switches itself off and I need to turn it back on.  We haven't experienced this behavior with any other phones, including others running 4.1.1 that I'm aware of.  I have two questions regarding this:

1. Does anyone know why?  I have my guesses, but I wanted to know if anyone has come across an actual validated answer for this.
2. Is there a way to force it to stay 'on' once it's switched on?

Thank you for any tips!

Comment: hi user2367193, what are your guesses? this sounds odd and shouldn't be happening - what is your build # (from settings)

Comment: Same here, btw, what are your guesses?

@dljava I've got Android 4.1.2, Build nr: 1.29.111.16 CL175272

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior. Android 4.1.2, build number 1.27.531.11 (T-Mobile, US)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue on huawei p9.

To solve the problem:

1. press "**restoring default settings**" if it exist(in huawei it's exist)
2. enter **developer mode setting**
3. enable **"OEM unlocking"**
4. now, enable **USB Debugging** - it should work.